# Why $EN < \infty $ implies $ N < \infty $?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Why $EN < \infty $ implies $ N < \infty $?  (It's part of Borel-Cantelli lemma's proof).

Comment: What is $E$ and $N$? (In particular, could any of them _fail_ to be finite and if so how?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\mathbb{E}[N] < \infty$, then necessarily $\mathbb{E}[N^+] < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[N^-] < \infty$, where $N^+(\omega): = \max\{N(\omega),0\}$ and $N^-(\omega): = \max\{-N(\omega),0\}$, the positive part and negative part of $N$ respectively.  This is because of how expectation is defined, as the sum of the expectations of the positive part and negative part.  Now, If $N$ (and thus $N^+$) took the value positive infinity on a set of positive measure $A$, then $\mathbb{E}N^+ \geq \mathbb{E}[N^+ \chi_A] = \infty$.

So since the expectation of $N$ is finite, the set where $N$ is infinite must have zero measure, or in other words, $N < \infty$ a.s.  The same argument applies to $N^-$, implying that the $N > -\infty$ a.s. as well.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, what does "a.s." mean?

Comment: a.s. is almost surely, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely for full description.

Comment: It is not true in general that $N \geq \chi_A$. But, $\mathbb{E}N < \infty \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}N^+ < \infty$, and $N^+ \geq \chi_A$. Maybe you should observe that.

Comment: Thank you Andre, you are right.  I have edited my answer to include this.